# Can I use the court report to show false statements?

Tags: texas, trial, perjury, civil

I have filed a Motion for New trial in Texas.  Lots of prejudice and bias on my end (not just me - all involved agree, of course).  I had 5 hearings in 1 day, attorney quit week before (I caught her lying - again).  It was a massacre.  Hard to become a lawyer in 2 weeks and the former attorney got 60K!  SO, I lost every hearing.  Even a Motion to Compel for 15 months!  Yep, I kid you not.

Court report shows all of the lies and misrepresentations.  I do not want to redo everything, especially lose the proof of lies and false information.

Can I suggest to the Judge to just go over the court report and correct the incorrect issues?  They definitely led to prejudice and bias and I think it would have had a different outcome.

Comment: Are you trying to ask if you can use statements from the old trial to justify a new trial, or in the new trial as evidence?

Comment: So... you should probably look for an attorney real quick BUT It would also help if you go into some details a bit.   It's hard to tell what happened in what order.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct the incorrect issues"?

Answer (score 1):

No, a new trial is just that- a new trial.

You cannot allude to the outcome of the earlier trial or pick and choose which bits of it you want to change. Though if it went as badly as you say it did, you wouldn't want to.